# Has anyone built an audio equivalent of this?

Tags: sound-design, audio, learning, machine

This is a tool which generates imagery based on text prompts using machine learning tools.  Does an equivalent for generating audio clips exist?

https://github.com/pixray/pixray

Comment: This probably belongs on https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: oops - apologies - moved to here: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/81461/has-anyone-built-an-audio-equivalent-of-this